# Best way to Iterate over a range of Integers in Java without regex

Tags: java, loops, iterator

I have range of numbers 08230 to 08239. I would like to iterate over this numbers and find numbers like 0823021267 or 0823121267 etc. I tried regex that works fine. Is there other way (better way) to do that and how please with example.

Comment: How do you have your range stored, what does it mean "numbers like (...)".

Comment: String telNr; So this is my input, and I need to find this telNr in the range above if yes then i show something. The named ranges are stored as int.

Comment: Then you don't want to iterate over numbers, but over strings, if leading zero makes a difference.

Comment: yes correct iterate over strings

Comment: If one leading zero is constant, you can simply prepend it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int min_range = 8230;
int max_range = 8239;


for(int i = min_range * 100000; i < max_range * 100000; ++i)
    System.out.println(i);
```

... if i understood what you meant correctly.
I would also want to ask someone with more knowledge whether the max_range * 100000 would be considered as loop invariant by javac and pulled out of the loop.